# Be able run graphql query on nfc tag discovery when app is not running

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

Hello I have app that whenever nfc tag is discovered it runs query gets data and then runs another query to update something.

My problem is that I can't make it work so that it works when app is in the background or not even on. Whenever I try to open app and hide it so its in the background and scan nfc tag some kind of default samsung nfc tag reading app pops up with tag data. I would like it to be my app instead and even better somehow make it so that my app even tho is not running will listen for nfc tag detection.

So far BroadcastReceiver and making a service didnt work for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your App cannot read NFC Tags in the background, it's just not a feature of Android.

The only thing you can do is add an [Android Application Record](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#aar) to the Tag, so that the system NFC service can install/start/bring to foreground your app so that it can then read the Tag when it is in the foreground.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. My nfc tags now start app but then I have to scan tag again to actually perform what I override in onTagDiscovered. Any idea why first nfc touch doesnt trigger that function and have to do it second time?

Comment: Depending on type of data stored on the Tag there might be an Intent passed to your App with some Tag data. You might also be able to also use an Intent filter (you could use a tech level Intent filter but that might bring up a app chooser). But without more details on the type of Tag/Data stored it's hard to propose this.